# How to use tab widget in Fragment class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I need a help in developing tab widgets in fragment class. I am new to android development.

Would be grateful if anyone helps me to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) can help.

Read [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.hk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for more information.